# HSK6 exam H61006: How do I infer the answers 28. 顺其自然 and 30. 就业率比西方国家高?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the transcript for questions 26-30 on the HSK6 past exam [H61006](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZlTgvC4NxE) (starting 18m30s):

> 男：您好，您觉得财富的好处有哪些？
>
> 女：我觉得财富带来最大的好处是让你有不做自己不喜欢事情的权利，从这一点来说，财富是非常值得拥有的。但如果想用财富去换得人性当中的爱、尊贵，你是买不到的，那些还需要你付出你的心，你的爱，去获取。
>
> 男：女人是否该建立自己的财富目标？
>
> 女：我认为女人应该有基本的财富保障。经济独立很重要，就算选择做家庭主妇，也要给自己一个基本的生活保障，因为这关系到一个人的尊严。曾有个资料表明，女性创业大多数都和爱好有关而不是纯粹的金钱目标，这是和男性大不相同的。至于你未来会有多少财富，这是可遇不可求的。
>
> 男：您认为未来中国，哪些行业更适合女性？
>
> 女：服务性的行业特别适合女性，它对人际交往、协调、沟通能力要求比较高，像传媒领域，现在主要的从业者都是女性，还有艺术、保险、银行、咨询、律师、生活类设计师，以及基于网络的很多小的产业，它不一定要求有大的投资，但需要有创意，有坚韧、细致入微的工作精神，这是女性更擅长的。
>
> 男：如果把财富圈比做一个俱乐部，在这个俱乐部里，女性是否真的实现了和男人平起平坐？
>
> 女：在中国，女性就业普遍比西方国家发达，但高层管理层的女性比例仍然是非常少的。女人们倒不一定会感觉有明显的歧视，但你需要证明自己。比如说，一个男人获得某种事业的成功后，其他男人就觉得：可以跟他做生意了；但一个女人往往需要几件事来证明自己：你的诚信，你的能力，你的各个方面的才华。相对来说女性付出的要比男性更多。

There are two questions I'm having problems with here:

> 28. **关于财富目标，女的是什么观点？**
>
>     - A. **顺其自然**
>     - B. 多多益善
>     - C. 要保守一些
>     - D. 一定要明确

> 30. **关于中国女性就业，下列哪项正确？**
>
>     - A. **就业率比西方国家高**
>     - B. 年轻女性更有竞争力
>     - C. 喜欢选择稳定的工作
>     - D. 在管理层所占比例很大

I highlight [the answers](http://jyangkul.net/HSK/HSK%206/HSK6%201/H61006%20answer.html) in bold.

I don't see how I can infer these answers from the given interview.  In my mind, the answer Question 28 is 应该有基本的财富保障, which is not an option.  And for Question 30, she says 女性就业普遍比西方国家发达, but I'm not clear on what it means for 就业 = "employment" to be 发达 = "developed", and how it implies answer A.

**Question**: How do I infer the answers 28. 顺其自然 and 30. 就业率比西方国家高?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

28. 关于财富目标，女的是什么观点？

- **A. 顺其自然(let nature take its course)**
- B. 多多益善(the more the better)
- C. 要保守一些(must be conservative)
- D. 一定要明确(must be clear-cut/definite)

"男：女人是否该建立自己的财富目标？

女：我认为女人应该有基本的财富保障。经济独立很重要，就算选择做家庭主妇，也要给自己一个基本的生活保障，因为这关系到一个人的尊严。曾有个资料表明，女性创业大多数都和爱好有关而不是纯粹的金钱目标，这是和男性大不相同的。至于你未来会有多少财富，**这是可遇不可求的**。"

The key lies in the phrase "可遇不可求的", which means "something can only be found by chance, and not through aggressively seeking." In the other word, it says "don't force the issue, let nature take its course - 顺其自然." Throughout the paragraph, nothing is ever close to the choice "B", "C", or "D", so the answer is "A".

30. 关于中国女性就业，下列哪项正确？

- **A. 就业率比西方国家高**
- B. 年轻女性更有竞争力
- C. 喜欢选择稳定的工作
- D. 在管理层所占比例很大

"女：在中国，**女性就业普遍比西方国家发达(developed/flourishing)，但高层管理层的女性比例仍然是非常少的**。"" This sentence clearly indicated "D" is false. Then, throughout the paragraph, there is no mention of "age" or "work safety", therefore, "B" and "C" are dropped out of consideration. Now, only "A" remains the possible choice.

Answer (score 1):

Question one: 至于你未来会有多少财富，这是可遇不可求的。 可遇不可求 is somewhat synonymous to 顺其自然。

Question two: 发达 is developed. I believe when you say developed in this scenario, it really means "something is more/better in quantity or quality". This is a case of the word "developed" used flexibly.

Quoting my high school teacher, on multiple choices,

> Choose the wrongest from the wrongs and the rightest from the rights (错中选错，对中选优)